# How can I insert a parent element to my json with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I want to insert new root element on my json with jq, my goal is to manipulate json hierarchy by adding one level before root one:

json example:

```
{
 "option1":true
}
```

i want to obtain:

```
{
 "root":
 {
  "option1":true
 }
}
```

but when i do:

`$ echo '{"option1":true}' | jq -r '. + {"root"}'`

it inserts the element at the first level, and not before it:

```
{
 "root":null
 "option1":true
}
```

Is it even possible ?

Comment: Not "bash jq", it's just "jq"; works the same way if you run it from Python or Java or any other language.

Comment: BTW, `-r` generally isn't the right tool when you want your output to be JSON itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `.` in the spot where you want your input data to be. In that case, that's as the value for which the `root` string is a key.

```
jq '{"root": .}' <<<'{"option1": true}'
```

...properly emits:

```
{
  "root": {
    "option1": true
  }
}
```

Comment: like u said a simple echo '{"option1":true}' | jq -r '{"root": .}' works exacly as expected :) thks !

Comment: Note that `echo` is not a particularly reliable tool; see the recommendation in the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX `echo` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) itself advising that `printf` be used instead.

Comment: And you shouldn't use the `-r` argument to `jq` when your intended output is JSON. It has no effect at all when the resulting element isn't a string, but when it *is* a string, it'll make it a raw one rather than valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

let me offer you an alternative approach, using a walk-path based unix utility **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**:

```
bash $  jtc -u'[^0]' -T'{ "root": {} }' -f file.json 
bash $ 
bash $ jtc file.json 
{
   "root": {
      "option1": true
   }
}
bash $
```

The changes applied right into the file (`-f` ensures that)

UPDATE: with the latest `jtc` version, template functionality has been extended, so for the same example to work, a slight change of template is required (`{}` needs to be spelled as `{{}}`):

```
bash $ jtc -u'[^0]' -T'{"root": {{}} }' file.json
{
   "root": {
      "option1": true
   }
}
bash $
```

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` tool

Comment: Would be good if the `jtc` manual would tell a bit about the differences, pros/cons compared to `jq`.

Comment: thank you for the comment, I'll come up with something in the near future

Answer (score 0):

How about plain `echo` and `cat`?

`echo "{\"root\":$(cat file.json)}" | jq`